# isotopologue distribution, difference among CID (carbon isotopologue distribution) and MID

Tags: isotopologues

I am new into LC-MS/MS stable isotope targeted downstream analysis. I've found numerous papers talking about MID (Mass isotopomer distribution) but in some european publications I found CID (carbon isotopologue distribution) and it seems to be the same, the vector of relative isotopologues abundances for a metabolite, could you please tell me if MID==CID ?  Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of isotopomers and isotopologues? Just like all oranges are fruits, but not all fruits are oranges, isotopologues and isotopomers are different types of isomers but not all isomers are isotopologues and isotopomers.

Comment: yes, I understand that isotopomers are indistinguishable in MS, so  $i$ labeled species are grouped in M+i isotopologue., but check for example ' Computational data mining method for isotopomer analysis in the quantitative assessment of metabolic reprogramming': " A metabolic flux ratio between two pathways can be estimated from the 13 C-labeling patterns or the *mass isotopomer distribution* vector (MDV) . The only vector that one can determine from MS is that of isotopologues , isn't it ?